# How to read from a File to a HashBiMap

Tags: java, filereader

I'm trying to read from a file using scanner and File Reader but I don't know why my code isn't putting the characters into the HashBiMap?

```
public class MappedCharCoder implements CharCoder {

private HashBiMap<Character, Character> codeKey = HashBiMap.create(26);

/**
 * The constructor takes a FQFN and reads from the file placing the contents
 * into a HashBiMap for the purpose of encryption and decryption.
 * 
 * @param map
 *            The variable map is the file name
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 *             If the file does not exist an exception will be thrown
 */
public MappedCharCoder(String map) throws FileNotFoundException {

    HashBiMap<Character, Character> code = this.codeKey;
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(map);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    int x = 0;
                    int y = 1;
        String cmd = scanner.next();
        cmd.split(",");
        char[] charArray = cmd.toCharArray();

        char key = charArray[x];
        if (code.containsKey(key)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "There are duplicate keys in the map.");
        }
        char value = charArray[y];
        if (code.containsValue(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "There are duplicate values in the map.");
        }
        code.forcePut(key, value);
                    x+=2;
                    y+=2;
    }

    scanner.close();

    if (code.size() > 26) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "The hashBiMap has more than 26 elements.");
    }

}

@Override
public char encode(char charToEncode) {
    char encodedChar = ' ';
    if (this.codeKey.containsKey(charToEncode)) {

        encodedChar = this.codeKey.get(charToEncode);
        return encodedChar;
    } else {
        return charToEncode;
    }

}

@Override
public char decode(char charToDecode) {

    char decodedChar = ' ';
    if (this.codeKey.containsValue(charToDecode)) {
        this.codeKey.inverse();
        decodedChar = this.codeKey.get(charToDecode);
        return decodedChar;
    } else {
        return charToDecode;
    }
}

}
```

As you can see from the code, I'm trying to create a substitution cipher.  If you guys could help me get this class working, hopefully I'll be able to get the other class working.  Thanks so much.

Comment: What do you expect the line `cmd.split(",")` to do?  (If the answer is "nothing," then good: your expectations match the actuality.)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The line in the file reads A,K etc.  The first character is the key separated by a comma then the value.  I thought that split() separated the String into two strings.  Could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: `cmd.split(",")` returns an array of `String`s.  If you don't do anything with the array it returns, then it's equivalent to doing nothing.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me how I can read in the key and the value without having to deal with the comma?

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.split(",")` returns a `String[]`, but you're immediately discarding the result of that.

What you *probably* want is something closer to

```
String[] chars = cmd.split(",");
char key = chars[0].charAt(0);
char value = chars[1].charAt(0);
// all the other checking you do
```

Also, FWIW, `HashBiMap` will already throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the value is already in the map.  (Not for the key, though.)